# Java android parse response from server to object or get a Value

Tags: java, android

Parse response from server to Object, I post to server a JSON and this is a answer :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><login_result><sctoken>a1fc912a-5c7a352b-8edf-4a54-a396-c6c5aea58c8b</sctoken><user_descr>Jan Nowak</user_descr><maps><tms><name>** MapCenterCache</name><url>http://cache2.smok.net.pl/cache_2015/element?s=%zoom%&amp;x=%x%&amp;y=%y%</url></tms><tms><name>OSM Mapnik</name><url>http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%zoom%/%x%/%y%.png</url></tms><tms><name>OSM****1</name><url>http://51.254.61.18:8104/tile/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/osm_server_elte/%zoom%/%x%/%y%.png</url></tms><tms><name>*****</name><url>http://mapa.***.net.pl/tms/%zoom%/%x%/%y%.png</url></tms></maps></login_result>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html may help

Answer (score 1):

The parsed Object is Root:

```
==================================
package ;
public class Tms
{
    private String name;

    private String url;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getUrl(){
        return this.url;
    }
}

==================================
package ;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Maps
{
    private List<Tms> tms;

    public void setTms(List<Tms> tms){
        this.tms = tms;
    }
    public List<Tms> getTms(){
        return this.tms;
    }
}

==================================
package ;
public class Login_result
{
    private String sctoken;

    private String user_descr;

    private Maps maps;

    public void setSctoken(String sctoken){
        this.sctoken = sctoken;
    }
    public String getSctoken(){
        return this.sctoken;
    }
    public void setUser_descr(String user_descr){
        this.user_descr = user_descr;
    }
    public String getUser_descr(){
        return this.user_descr;
    }
    public void setMaps(Maps maps){
        this.maps = maps;
    }
    public Maps getMaps(){
        return this.maps;
    }
}

==================================
package ;

    public class Root
    {
        private Login_result login_result;

        public void setLogin_result(Login_result login_result){
            this.login_result = login_result;
        }
        public Login_result getLogin_result(){
            return this.login_result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok but could you tell me how I can use this in my apk ?

Comment: This is parsed Response from the server for sure,if u want to use it in the Apk it depends upon your apk requirement,U can fetch whatever data u want from the classes above.

Comment: plz upvote it if u find it useful

Comment: Ok but this response I have on string so how I can create a object or get value from column ?

Comment: Use Java Jackson Library to deserialize the Server response to the Root Object.

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here on how to parse XML
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Example:

```
public void parseXml(){
    try {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput( new StringReader( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) ); // pass input whatever xml you have
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Start document");
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Start tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                Log.d(TAG,"End tag "+xpp.getName());
            } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Text "+xpp.getText()); // here you get the text from xml
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"End document");

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```